# Firebase app not initialized on Google Cloud

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm connecting to `firestore` on my `spring boot app`. The app gets initialised and works completely fine locally. However, as soon as I deploy it to Google Cloud it, I get this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.   at
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:164)
>   ~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar!/:na]  at
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:135)
>   ~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar!/:na]  at
>   com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:64)
>   ~[firebase-admin-6.8.1.jar!/:na]  at
>   com.augiemarketplace.augiemarketplaceapi.service.AugieMarketService.getListOfAllItems(AugieMarketService.java:112)
>   ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

The code I am using to initialize the spring app:

```
try {
 if (!FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
 }
 FileInputStream serviceAccount =
  new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/firebase.json");
 FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://augiemarketplace.firebaseio.com")
  .build();
 if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The line of code I am using to call `Firestore`:

```
Firestore dbFireStore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

Comment: From the error message is seems that the first block of code wasn't called, or didn't correctly initialize the `FirebaseApp` instance before the second block of code was run.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes it's hard to debug it since that block of code is in my config file and since it is working fine on my local ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged my app and came to the conclusion that relative file paths don't get detected when I deploy my app to the Google Cloud Platform. I am not sure how to specify paths on App Engine. Code I am using to access my file:

`FileInputStream serviceAccount =
  new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/firebase.json");`

ANSWER: went with a different approach just use this call to serve static files: `InputStream serviceAccount = new ClassPathResource("firebase.json").getInputStream();`

Comment: Could you share with us what are you using this paths for and how are you accessing to them? (maybe with a code snippet)

Comment: @LuisManuel same code I posted `FileInputStream serviceAccount =
  new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/firebase.json");`